What exactly happens if you don’t have the minimum stats for something?
A lot of the different gear in Elden Ring has at least one minimum stat you need for that gear to be fully effective.
For example, if you want to use a certain weapon, you might be required to have a minimum Strength of 15 and a minimum Dexterity of 16, and if you don’t, you will be warned with a message saying something along the lines of “this weapon will not work correctly with your current stats” (though you can still equip it).
What exactly happens though? Do you do less damage? Does it depend on the stat(s) you’re missing? Does it depend on the type of gear you want to use?

The other answer makes a couple of sweeping statements, but they're not entirely true.
In general, your damage will be severely reduced to the point of making the weapon unusable, but there are a couple of things to note.
Two-handing a weapon adds 50% to your strength stat. So while you might not meet the weapon's requirements, two-handing it could put you over the minimum strength level required.
For weapons with a elemental component based on Int or Faith scaling (for example Helphen's Steeple), not meeting the requirements in those stats will only affect the elemental damage of the weapon. If you do have the Dex and Str requirements, you might be able to use the weapon with only slightly reduced damage output. This also does not incur the other penalties mentioned in Malady's answer.

Since our answers are two parts of a complete answer, do you mind if I copy your info into mine? Or do you want to take my info?

What parts of the other answer are sweeping statements that are not entirely true? It looks accurate to me.

@Parrotmaster mostly the thing in my last paragraph. The stamina consumption and deflecting doesn't necessarily happen if you're missing only certain stats.

So... Do you mind if I edit your answer into mine? Or do you want to take my answer instead? Better to have one answer with all the details than split it out.

Are you the one upvoting my comments? If so, please @ me to respond, because I wouldn't want to assume.

@Malady That was me.

@Daemons - Thanks for the support!

Honestly, I think two answers is fine.

@JAD Yes, but it’d be better if the accepted answer had all the info.

According to a comment by user sunm8 on the Reddit thread What happens when you don’t meet the requirement for a weapon?:

Terrible damage. You can't properly use the weapon art. More stamina consumption. Your attacks will be deflected when blocked, even when two handed.

From a previous comment on this site, getting into specifics about "You can't properly use the weapon art.":

Regarding the weapon art: how it "fails" changes per weapon art. You will still do the animation, but the associated effect won't happen. If a weapon art causes you to raise your sword and summon small magical blades, only the sword raising will happen. This is relevant because Quickstep will still make you dash a short distance. It just won't give you invulnerability frames. You can still use that for niche applications.

Parrotmaster - Commented 2024-10-03 06:26:00Z
And from another previous comment on here:

tl;dr it's only really useful for testing to see if you like the weapon's moveset - in previous games, not meeting stat requirements meant you had a completely different flailing attacking animation, which wasn't helpful. At least in ER, you can see if you like a weapon's moveset before you decide to allocate points to it

Pyritie - Commented 2024-10-02 14:38:24Z

afaik, "previous games" stopped after dark souls 1. I'm pretty sure 2 let you use the same moveset regardless of stats. The only limitation there would be powerstancing, which also requires 150% of the listed stats.

@qazmlpok - If you confirm that it's a DS1 thing, I'll change the wording.

I can confirm that it happens in DS1 and not DS2, but not that it happens/doesn't in Demon's Souls, which I've never played. While it's not precisely a previous game, DS1 is very much a spiritual successor, and I assume Demon's does the same thing, but can't confirm.

@qazmlpok - Ah well. If anyone wants to know 'bout Demon / Dark Souls instead of Elden Ring, they could make a new question, I guess.
